# Filter array with multiple conditions and that some of them can be null

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, multiple-conditions

I have a JS file that is used to render a vuetify v-list, which can have 2 levels (nodes with children and these are optional).

I need to add a filter from a search box that the user enters, I could filter the first level, but I have problems with the second because sometimes they have the property "children" in null and other times they have values. The menu is this:

```
const Menu = [
    {
        heading: null,
        icon: "mdi-security",
        text: "Login",
        url: {
            name: "login"
        },
        exactUrl: false,
        children: null,
        meta: {
            publicPath: true
        }
    },
    {
        heading: null,
        icon: "search",
        text: "Lista de Funcionarios",
        url: {
            name: "home"
        },
        exactUrl: true,
        children: null,
        meta: {
            publicPath: true
        }
    },
    {
        heading: {
            text: "Mantenimientos",
            publicPath: false
        },
        icon: null,
        text: "",
        url: null,
        exactUrl: null,
        children: null,
        meta: null
    },
    {
        heading: null,
        icon: "mdi-account-group",
        text: "Departamentos",
        url: {
            name: "departamentos"
        },
        exactUrl: false,
        children: null,
        meta: {
            publicPath: false
        }
    },
    {
        heading: null,
        icon: "mdi-account-circle",
        text: "Funcionarios",
        url: {
            name: "funcionarios"
        },
        exactUrl: false,
        children: null,
        meta: {
            publicPath: false
        }
    },
    {
        heading: null,
        icon: "settings",
        text: "Operación",
        url: null,
        exactUrl: false,
        children: [{
            icon: "add",
            text: "Cargar Pedidos",
            url: {
                name: "departamentos"
            }
        },
        {
            icon: "playlist_add_check",
            text: "Aprobar Pedidos",
            url: {
                name: "areas"
            }

        },
        {
            icon: "content_copy",
            text: "Remitir Pedidos",
            url: {
                name: "maps"
            }
        }
        ],
        meta: null
    },
];

export default Menu;
```

And my computed function is this:

```
filteredMenu() {
  return this.menus.filter(menu =>
    menu.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
  );
}
```

How could I filter at the same time on both levels?

EDIT 1:"

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a simple demo?

Comment: yes, I have added an image of the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this, which of course uses recursion. The way it uses recursion is important, though, meaning you want to probe the children *first*, then following determine if there are children (keeps the parent), *or* if the current menu item has the given text, it matches. You'll want the parent for any matching children, going all the way inward for each branching of your menu structure, then work your way back to the root-level items.

This will call the probe on the children, which then runs the whole procedure further inward, until there are no children, returning each inward set with matches (and it's associated parent item), then backing up to work on the next higher level. Think of it like this diagram,

```
1 match
2 match
        3az < match
        3ay < match
        3ax < match
    3a < [...match] match
    3b < match
3 [...match] match
    4a < match
4 [...match] match
5 match
```

Also, you don't want to filter, you want to *reduce to a set*.

```
const search = (items, text) => {
  const hasText = item => item.text.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())
  const probe = (found, item) => {
    item.children = (item.children || []).reduce(probe, [])

    if (item.children.length || hasText(item)) {
      found.push(item)
    }

    return found
  }

  return items.reduce(probe, [])
}

... elsewhere ...

return search(this.menus, 'c')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/81wkh5df/6/

This returns:

- Lista de Funcionarios
- Funcionarios
- Operación

  - Cargar Pedidos

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that you can call recursively.

```
methods: {
  filterMenuItems(menuItems) {
    return menuItems.filter(menuItem => {
      let found = menuItem.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      if (!found && Array.isArray(menuItem.children)) {
        found = this.filterMenuItems(menuItem.children);
      }
      return found;
    });
  }
}
```

Now your computed property can return `this.filterMenuItems(this.menus)`

```
filteredMenu() {
    return this.filterMenuItems(this.menus);
}
```

This allows for infinite sublevels as well

Comment: I really liked your recursive proposal, although it didn't work at all. I have added some console.log to check the filters.

With the filter "ar" excludes "Login" of the first level, but does not exclude "Remitir Pedidos" of the second level, although in the console it is seen that the match is printed "false".

I leave a capture of the result: https://i.imgur.com/i2blR9k.png

Comment: This is expected. 1 of the child items contains "ar" (Cargar Pedidos). We don't filter out child items.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in order to get a value and set a predefined value, then using [Some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) you can check for a `truthy` condition on an `Array`.

so in other words, what you need to do is the following:

```
filteredMenu() {
  return this.menus.filter(menu => {
    // check if the parent has the value
    const parentIncludesText = menu.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())

    // define a predefined value in case 'children' is null
    const { children = [] } = menu || {}

    // check if some of the childs has the value.
    const childrenIncludesText = children.some(child => child.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))

    // then return the result of the parent and the children.
    return parentIncludesText || childrenIncludesText
  });
}
```

Comment: Where's the destructuring?

Comment: @JaredFarrish
`const { children = [] } = menu|| {}`

Comment: That's a way of doing it. The way you had it before (`const children = menu.children || []`) worked fine as well. I'd give you an upvote without it (I think it confuses the issue), but won't downvote it either.

Comment: yes @JaredFarrish as soon as you told me, I noticed :) thank you for noticing that before :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use  a helpful function _isExist()

```
const _isExist = (menu, value) => menu.text.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
```

and you can use it for searching inside the children array if exist

```
filteredMenu() {
  return this.menus.filter(
    menu =>
        _isExist(menu, this.search) ||
        (menu.children && menu.children.some(childMenu => _isExist(childMenu, this.search))),
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If im correct you want to check if its children is not null too? You can use `&&`

```
filteredMenu() {
  return this.menus.filter(menu =>
    menu.children && menu.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
  );
}
```

Comment: No, the filter condition has to be:

1. The text property of the first level must be filtered even if children are null or have value.
2. If children is not null, this must also be filtered by the text property